# using python open different cmd prompts and run different adb shell commands continously

Tags: python-2.7

setup details: an android device connected to windows7

my intention is to open a cmd prompt on windows 7 and run continuously  "adb shell ping 192.168.1.22"
while in parallel open other cmd prompt and run continuously "adb shell ping 192.168.1.100"

i want these windows to open and run independently 
please help to achieve this!!!

```
import os
os.system("adb root ")
os.system("adb shell ping -i 0.01 192.168.1.22")
os.system("adb shell ping -i 0.01 192.168.1.100")
```

Comment: Any particular results you wish to get from these?

Comment: yes during some test need to check the behavior of pings to these destination IPs

Comment: could it ping one then the other and then repeat, then split the data?

Comment: actually in parallel to this i want to run logcat and kmsg logs along with netstat data, so cant run and split later, need data at live

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here goes

on my computer One.py

```
//One.py

import os
os.chdir("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Android\\android-sdk\\platform-tools")
os.system("adb shell ping  192.168.1.1")
```

then Two.py

```
//Two.py

import os
os.chdir("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Android\\android-sdk\\platform-tools")
os.system("adb shell ping  8.8.8.8")
```

Then MultipleWindows.py

```
//MultipleWindows.py

import os

os.chdir("C:\\Python27")

os.system('start "Window 1" python.exe One.py ')
os.system('start "Window 2" python.exe Two.py ')
```

Comment: Thanks  Pomadomaphin, isnt there a better solution rather than creating multiple .py files. As need to run multiple other commands thats concludes to be huge number of .py file :(

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, make one python file with all of the command options you want.

#Three.py

```
import os
import sys


os.chdir("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Android\\android-sdk\\platform-tools")

print(sys.argv)

if sys.argv[1]=='ping':
    os.system("adb shell ping  %s" %sys.argv[2])


if sys.argv[1]=='other':
    os.system("adb shell [whatever other does]  %s" %sys.argv[2])
```

Then the controler script is just the same as the one i mentioned earlier

```
#controler
import os

os.chdir("C:\\Python27")

#os.system('start "Window 1" python.exe Three.py ping 192.168.1.1')
#os.system('start "Window 2" python.exe Three.py other argumentsforother ')


def Command(Type,Argument):
    os.system('start "(%s,%s)" python.exe Three.py %s %s' %(Type,Argument,Type,Argument))


Command('ping','192.168.1.1')
```

Add your own commands and arguments as you please.

Comment: Adding code in the form of if statements will allow you to perform multiple tasks on multiple different arguments. you can now use a single command program to ping whatever ip address you like.  Just replace "other" with valid adb commands and the arguments required.